# Python Tkinter Run Checkbuttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to write a python script, where I have some Checkbuttons and a Button for Running my active checkbuttons. If a checkbutton is active and i click on "Run" the def run_app should check which checkbuttons are active. But if I run my code, the terminal says, that the global name "is_checked" is not defined.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import sys
import os.path
import subprocess

exe = (path of my exe)  
call = exe

class App:
  def __init__(self, master):
    self.is_checked = IntVar()
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.test = Checkbutton(frame, 
                     text="Verzeichnisse",
                     )
    self.test.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.slogan = Checkbutton(frame,
                     text="Visual Studio",
                     onvalue=1, 
                     offvalue=0, 
                     variable=self.is_checked

                     )
    self.slogan.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.button = Button(frame, 
                     text="RUN", fg="red",
                     command=self.run_app)
    self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

 def open_vb(self):
    subprocess.call(call, shell=True)

 def run_app(self):
    if self.is_checked.get():
        command=self.open_vb



root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_checked` created locally which means there is no `is_checked` variable outside of your `__init__`.

If you want to use that variable outside of where it is created, you need to either make it `global` or bind to a class. Since you already have class structure, it is better to use latter one.

You need to change `is_checked` to `self.is_checked` everywhere to make that variable is a part of class.

Comment: i changed is_checked to self.is_checked . Now I dont get any error, but my exe doenst open :/ ( changed the code of my question too )

Comment: @Dennis You shouldn't make edits to your question which makes answers irrelevant. Also, I don't  see what do you mean in `command=self.open_vb` this line? If you want to execute `self.open_vb` you need `self.open_vb()` instead of that.

Comment: Okay sorry.. I guess i fixed it. :)

Comment: @Dennis No worries. :) Also if this answer solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.